# Workbook.SaveCopyAs Method (Excel) returns Run-time error '1004'

Tags: vba, excel

It is Office 2016 Mac OS edition issue.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim FilenameStr As String
    FilenameStr = Sheet1.Range("F11").Value
    FilenameStr = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/" & FilenameStr & "_" & Sheet1.Range("I5").Value
```

Or this as an alternative for the previous line

```
FilenameStr = FilenameStr & "_" & Sheet1.Range("I5").Value
```

At this point I get the FilenameStr like this
/Users/myusername/somedir/123456789_20130531-002

```
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (FilenameStr & ".xls")
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

This is the error I'm getting
Run-time error '1004': Cannot access read-only document 123456789_20130531-002.xls

The file doesn't exist and has to be created, but everythig worked back in Office 2011.

Comment: at work we have been moved over to ms teams for shared folders/files and `.savecopyas` fails for me as well:
`test save returned: "Sorry, we couldn't find https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx\load 171009 (v5.5) (FOR LOADING).xlsm. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted? (1004)"`.
 
I wondered if the backslash was causing this however `.saveas` works fine